# MySQL : can CASE - vary its query between Insert or Select?

Tags: mysql, case

Is it possible to have one query that will check if criteria are met, and depending on the answer either a) `INSERT` or b) `UPDATE` ?

(better example suggested in answer by Mandar)

```
CASE 
   WHEN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT action FROM database where action = 'eat' AND user = 'me') 
      THEN  (UPDATE database set action = 'digest' where user = 'me')
   WHEN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT action FROM database where action = 'inhale' AND user = 'me') 
      THEN  (UPDATE database set action = 'exhale' where user = 'me')

   ELSE (INSERT INTO database (user,action) VALUES ('me','living'))
END CASE
```

It does not give the expected result.

Comment: You'll probably have to resort to a stored procedure.  The pseudo code you posted could easily be done in a stored procedure.

Comment: I've trimmed down my question to hopefully make it more clear..I'd like to do various 'inserts' and 'updates' depending on the result of a select statement.

Answer (score 2):

Use IF EXISTS

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT action FROM database where action = 'eat' AND user = 'me') 
 THEN  (UPDATE database set action = 'digest' where user = 'me')

ELSE (INSERT INTO database (user,action) VALUES ('me','eat'))
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't working...Getting an error to check syntax on the first line.

Comment: CASE WHEN EXISTS (select ... )
THEN INSERT
ELSE UPDATE 
This will work as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: Sorry. This does not work. 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT action FROM playlog where action = 'eat' AND user = 'm' at line 1

Comment: How about using @@ROWCOUNT to count the number of rows after select and then insert or update depending on value of @@ROWCOUNT ?

Comment: I like the idea of your answer you posted...Was it wrong or is it some syntax error? Your original answer I think will be most helpful

Answer (score 1):

If `(action, user)` is a unique key in your table, you could use the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax to achieve this:

```
INSERT INTO database (user,action) VALUES ('me','eat')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Action='digest';
```

Comment: I'm going to have many rows with the same user and many of those rows with the same actions

Comment: @light: How can that be, when after the first such `(user,action)` pair is inserted all subsequent actions merely perform an `UPDATE`?

Comment: its only this example, sorry. Unfortunately, There will be more constraints in addition to user and action.

Comment: @light: Please edit your question to provide a more appropriate example.  As things stand, this answer is by far the best solution.

Comment: @iight: Your intent is ambiguous when your problem description involves a table called 'database'. Perhaps you are using digestion as an analogy for your real purpose. 
It may be clearer if you stated more about the actual problem that you are modelling and posted the relevant portions of the database schema.

Comment: @ChrisGuest, very good point; duly noted.
I've added a little more code which will hopefully convey the goal I'm trying to accomplish. i'd like to set different criteria which will determine the query that is run (whether 'insert' or 'update'). I think the 'IF EXISTS' answer from below is close to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions on what you want. I'll suggest the you create a stored procedure for that. Example

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertOrUpdate
BEGIN
    DECLARE `result` int;
    SET `result` := (   
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM database
                        WHERE action = 'eat' AND
                             `user` = 'me'
                    );
    IF  `result` > 0 THEN
        UPDATE database 
        SET action = 'digest' 
        WHERE user = 'me';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO database (user,action) 
        VALUES ('me','eat');
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Usage,

```
call InsertOrUpdate();
```